# Scala Play Framework DB Shutdown Lifecycle Hook Order

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I have a Scala (2.11.x), Play 2.5.10 application. Within this application, I have various Akka actors which read and write data to the database. I am terminating these actors via a lifecycle stop hook as described [in the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection). For one of these actors, before sending in the `PoisonPill` to terminate it, I'd like to send it a message to make one final write to the database. However, I'm receiving an exception because the database connections have already been terminated (sometimes, it's a race condition) when that message is received.

Is there a way to control the lifecycle shutdown hook execution order in Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [scaladoc](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/inject/ApplicationLifecycle.scala) it says:

> Stop hooks are executed when the application is shutdown, in reverse from when they were registered.

So, not really.

You might be able to handle it purely from within your actors though. Here's a guide on how to coordinate shutdown in an actor system. I'm not sure how well this integrates with your play-based application though: http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thank you.